# Plone 4.3 migration - AttributeError: type object 'IIntIds' has no attribute '__iro__'

Tags: plone

After migrating Plone 4.1 + Dexterity site to Plone 4.3 site's /manage_workspace becomes inaccessible. Database migration cannot be performed.

The ZMI root can be still accessed.

```
Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 237, in publish_module_standard
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 179, in publish
    Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
    Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
    Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
    Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
    Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
    Module plone.transformchain.zpublisher, line 119, in applyTransformOnFailure
    Module plone.transformchain.zpublisher, line 79, in applyTransformOnSuccess
    Module plone.transformchain.zpublisher, line 55, in applyTransform
    Module zope.component._api, line 172, in queryUtility
    Module zope.component.registry, line 163, in queryUtility
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 860, in setstate
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 914, in _setstate
    Module ZODB.serialize, line 613, in setGhostState
    Module zope.component.persistentregistry, line 40, in __setstate__
    Module zope.interface.adapter, line 91, in _createLookup
    Module zope.interface.adapter, line 439, in __init__
    Module zope.interface.adapter, line 476, in init_extendors
    Module zope.interface.adapter, line 480, in add_extendor

AttributeError: type object 'IIntIds' has no attribute '__iro__'
```

Also `@@plone-upgrade` is inaccessible.

Any ideas or special migrations needed?

Comment: Is IntIds still being used by Dexterity et. al or can I rip it off from the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Dexterity 2, relation field support (which includes installing the intids catalog) is no longer installed by default. To get it you need to install Dexterity with the [relations] extra:

```
[instance]
eggs =
    plone.app.dexterity [relations]
```

This is documented at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-4.2-to-4.3/dexterity-optional-extras and in the Dexterity release notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The tricky part was to map exception traceback to release notes. I have updated the installation manual: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-4.2-to-4.3/changed-imports-and-functions